# Representation of SVD decomposition as sum of rank 1 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Say that one writes the SVD decomposition of a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ as $U \Sigma V^T$. If we know $X$ has rank $r \lt n$ (assume $n \lt m$) then apparently it holds that $X$ can be written as

$$ \sum_{i=1}^r \sigma_i(X)u_iv_i^T$$

Where $u_i$ and $v_i$ are the column vectors of $U$ and $V$ respectively and the $\sigma$s are the singular values of $X$. Rather than a proof of this, I would like to have a point of view that makes it intuitive.

Comment: Beyond the simple algebra, (see @copper.hat's answer), what are you looking for?

Comment: It didn't look obvious enough to me. I could see the proof, but had a hard time finding it a natural fact.

Comment: What is intuitive to you?  Are you comfortable with the concept of a rank r matrix? What does it mean to you intuitively?

Comment: I tried to compute the double product directly and without using the trick of comparing how they act on some vector $x$, but got lost in the indices. Somehow, applying the two things to $x$ makes it so much more straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U\Sigma V^T x = U \Sigma \begin{bmatrix} v_1^T x \\ \vdots \\ v_m^T x\end{bmatrix}= U  \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_1 v_1^T x \\ \vdots \\ \sigma_m v_m^T x\end{bmatrix} = \sum_k u_k \sigma_k v_k^T x = \sum_k \sigma_k u_k  v_k^T x$.

Hence $U \Sigma V^T = \sum_k \sigma_k u_k  v_k^T$.